# Google Apps Script to relace a placeholder in Document with filtered rows in a google sheet

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a google apps script to replace a place holder in a google document with a table from google sheets after filtering it with let's say (ProjectID = 123).

It doesn't work at all. Can you please tell me why?

```
function replacePlaceholderWithTable() {
  // Define the key to match rows in the Google Sheet
  var keyToMatch = "123";

  // Get the active Google Document
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // Define the placeholder text in the Google Document
  var placeholder = "{{TABLE_PLACEHOLDER}}";

  // Find and replace the placeholder with the table
  var element = body.findText(placeholder);
  
  if (element) {
    // Get the location of the placeholder
    var startOffset = element.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = element.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    // Get the content between the start and end offsets
    var content = body.getText().substring(startOffset, endOffset + 1);

    // Get the table data from the Google Sheet
    var tableData = getTableDataFromSheet(keyToMatch);

    // Create a new table in the Google Document
    var table = body.insertTable(startOffset, tableData.length + 1, tableData[0].length);
    
    // Populate the table with data
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) {
        table.getCell(i + 1, j).setText(tableData[i][j]);
      }
    }

    // Remove the placeholder text
    body.deleteText(startOffset, endOffset + 1);
  }
}

function getTableDataFromSheet(keyToMatch) {
  // Get the active Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Replace "Sheet1" with the actual sheet name

  // Get all data from the sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Filter rows based on the key
  var filteredData = data.filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] === keyToMatch; // Assuming the key is in the first column
  });

  return filteredData;
}
```